# Атрибут hidden не работает в js коде

Tags: javascript, hidden

Пытался решить задачу по js, где надо написать код, который при клике на div превращался бы в textarea, где можно редактировать html код, а при расфокусировке отображал бы уже отредактированный вариант. Но столкнулся с со следующей проблемой, которую никак не могу понять.

Я хотел сделать через атрибут hidden, следующим образом:

```
    let div = document.getElementById(`container`);
    let textarea = document.createElement(`textarea`);
    let divOuter = div.querySelector(`#userText`);
    
    div.addEventListener(`click`, showTextarea);
    
    function showTextarea() {
      divOuter.hidden = true;
      textarea.value = divOuter.outerHTML;
      div.append(textarea);
      textarea.focus();
    };
    
    div.addEventListener(`focusout`, closeTextarea);
    
    function closeTextarea() {
      
      divOuter.outerHTML = textarea.value;
    
      console.log(divOuter.hidden)
    
      divOuter.hidden = false;
    
      console.log(divOuter.hidden)
    
      textarea.hidden = true;
    }
```

Почему-то при расфокусировке `divOuter.hidden = false` не срабатывает, div не появляется, хотя вторая консоль выводит false.

**Почему `divOuter.hidden = false` не срабатывает по факту?**

Но если добавить новую переменную с ссылкой на тот же div элемент вот так:

```
    function closeTextarea() {
      
      divOuter.outerHTML = textarea.value;
    
      console.log(divOuter.hidden)
    
      divOuter.hidden = false;
    
      console.log(divOuter.hidden)
    
      textarea.hidden = true;
    
      let _divOuter = div.querySelector(`#userText`);
      console.log(_divOuter.hidden)
      _divOuter.hidden = false;
      console.log(_divOuter.hidden)
    };
```

То hidden в этом случае всё же сменяется в DOM и отображает div. Если честно, даже придумать не могу что-нибудь, почему это так работает.

HTML был следующим:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="container">
      <div id="userText">
        <h1>Write here</h1>
        <p>ok</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: а где в разметке `textarea`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основная проблема в использовании `outerHTML`.

Строчка

```
textarea.value = divOuter.outerHTML;
```

располагается ниже строчки

```
divOuter.hidden = true;
```

из-за этого этот атрибут есть в редактируемом тексте.

При обратной подстановке свойство меняется у исходного дива, и далее этот див полностью заменяется на то, что было внутри `textarea`, и, так как в значении не изменялся этот атрибут - он возвращается на место.

---

Вместо полной смены дива лучше использовать его `innerHTML`, тогда не нужно будет обновлять ссылку на него при каждом закрытии.

Например:

```js
let div = document.getElementById(`container`);
let textarea = document.createElement(`textarea`);
let divOuter = div.querySelector(`#userText`);

let isEditing = false;

div.addEventListener(`click`, toggleTextarea);

function toggleTextarea() {
  isEditing = !isEditing;
  if (isEditing) {
    showTextarea();
  } else {
    closeTextarea();
  }
}

function showTextarea() {
  textarea.value = divOuter.innerHTML;

  divOuter.hidden = true;
  textarea.hidden = false;

  div.append(textarea);
  textarea.focus();
};

textarea.addEventListener(`focusout`, closeTextarea);
textarea.addEventListener('click', e => e.stopPropagation());

function closeTextarea() {
  divOuter.hidden = false;
  textarea.hidden = true;
  divOuter.innerHTML = textarea.value;
}
```

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  /* height: 100px;*/
}

#userText {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.ccc {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="userText">
    <h1>Write here</h1>
    <p>ok</p>
  </div>
</div>
```